# Question regarding finding subspaces of a kernel of a function.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Task: Let $\phi_A:\mathbb{R}^5 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, A = \begin{bmatrix}1,1,1,1,1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\mathbb{W} = ker\phi_A$. Find two subspaces $\mathbb{U_1}$, $\mathbb{U_2}$ of $\mathbb{W}$ such that dim$\mathbb{U_1}$ = dim$\mathbb{U_2}$ = $2$ and $\mathbb{U_1} \cap \mathbb{U_2} = 0$

Solution: I considered $\mathbb{U_1} = \{\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\0\end{bmatrix}\}$,
$\mathbb{U_2} = \{\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\1\end{bmatrix}\}$

Multiplying A by any vector from $\mathbb{U_1}$ or $\mathbb{U_2}$ gives 0 (is it correct?). Also $\mathbb{U_1} \cap \mathbb{U_2} = 0$ which I proved using Zassenhaus algorithm.

Is my solution correct? If it's not, could you explain to me how should I interpret the problem? I still don't quite understand how the function $\phi_A$ really works.

Comment: Your solution is correct.